# SUMProduct or Sum if to only count values in multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use `sumproduct` to count multiple rows if the formula finds a match in a particular column.  I'm using  the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="IMRT Treatments Commercial")*('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO))+SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="IMRT TX to Medicare plans (G Codes)")*('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO))+SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="Daily Treatments Commercial Plans")*('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO))+SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="Daily TX to Medicare plans (G codes)")*('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO))
```

It works fine, except currently there are no values for columns `AE:AO`, as those are future months, and they are displaying as `#DIV/0`, which is giving my formula total a `#DIV/0`.  Is there a way to count the columns only when they have a total. So when `AE` has a 4, it will count it, but not if it is displaying `#Div/0`?

In a hidden cell, I've put a formula that will display the columns if a certain month is entered.  For example, when February is typed it, the formula displays `AD:AE`.  I tried linking that formula into my `sumif`, but it is pulling like this: `")*('CPT Utilization'!G15))`.

`G15` is on another sheet, so that is not working correctly.

Comment: If you don't mind.. you may accept the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It'll remove this question from SO 'unanswered' list. || Alternatively if the example doesn't work for you.. please share the details here. ( :

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Count not the Sum you can use ISNUMBER like the following:

`=SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="IMRT Treatments Commercial")(ISNUMBER('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO)))+SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="IMRT TX to Medicare plans (G Codes)")(ISNUMBER('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO)))+SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="Daily Treatments Commercial Plans")(ISNUMBER('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO)))+SUMPRODUCT(('CPT Utilization'!C:C="Daily TX to Medicare plans (G codes)")(ISNUMBER('CPT Utilization'!AD:AO)))`

In this case if in  'CPT Utilization'!AD:AO there is text or #Div/0 it will not be included.